# c# simulate mouse click & javascript this

Tags: c#, automation, mouseevent, webbrowser-control, mouse

I am experiencing some problems with automatic mouse click in c# WebBrowser. I can use RaiseEvent("OnMouseDown"); but it doesn't work as I expected in this case.

I definitely prefer to use mouse_event or SendInput. It does click as well, but the difference is that two functions don't pass javascript this correctly to browser.

Example (page I load in c# webbrowser to make a click):

```html
<script>
  function sayHello(x) {
   x.href="#zonk";
   alert("Hello!");
  }
</script>
<a onmousedown="sayHello(this)" href="#">TEST</a>
```

Alert always work (onmousedown, mouse_event, sendinput), but changing any an attribute of a element only works with RaiseEvent.